# using HTML Agility Pack to verify HTML not working for me

Tags: html-agility-pack

not sure if I'm missing some option, but `<div><b>hello</div>` says it's ok (no errors), this is the code (vb) ...

```
Dim htmlDoc = New HtmlDocument()
htmlDoc.Loadhtml("<div><b>hello</div>")
```

htmlDoc.ParseErrors.count is 0

Am I missing setting an option or something?

PD: I tried `htmlDoc.Loadhtml("<b>hello")` and that does return as invalid, not sure why the unclosed `<b>` inside the `<div>` doesn't.
(I originally posted this in the "code review" site and they said this belonged to Stack Overflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library is clearly not a validating tool. The `ParsedErrors` collection is more a hint for serious problems (that the library considers itself as a serious problem).

If you want a validating tool, [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) is the standard.

Comment: ok I'm trying HTML Tidy. Looks overkillish but if it works it works. I found a refererence for the options, but not sure how to set it to just validate a string?

Comment: Don't know that library myself, you should ask another question.